# String List in ActionScript-3?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, list

How can I have a **string list** in ActionScript-3 ? I don't want to just use an array and always check for type or be type vulnerable. If I could make arrays type specific that would help me. In C# I can do:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("hello world");
string str = list[0];
```

I wished I could do more or less the same in AS-3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Vector`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html) type, like this:

```
var list:Vector.<String> = new <String>[];
//                      or new Vector.<String>();

list.push("hello world");
var str:String = list[0];
```

Note that AS3's `Vector` class lacks some functionality found in C#'s `List<T>` like `Remove()`, and includes some functionality you would find in other classes of C# such as `pop()`, typically found in `Stack<T>`.

Comment: @mini-me Actually, `[]` is the correct syntaxif you want to use the shorthand `new <Type>[]` constructor, and I meant *would* (`pop()` is a method of `Stack<T>` in C#).

Comment: Ok, sorry. Good thing there is the review feature on SO. You confused me all the way :)

Comment: @mini-me It's fine, we encourage editing if you think something is wrong so thanks for giving it a go.

Answer (score 1):

In AS3 you can use `Vector` datatype.

See [More info on Vector data type](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html)

Answer (score 0):

`Vector` class works the same way as you need.

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html.